# What happens if I save my fields for next summer in Puzzle Craft?

Tags: puzzle-craft

What happens if I save my fields for next summer in Puzzle Craft? Is the complete field saved, or just the valuable tiles?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the valuable tiles are saved - so just the 5 carrots and 2 pigs in your example.  They will be randomly distributed along with the standard starting tiles, on the next time you visit the farm.